# como criar um Menu com ListView

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Como faço para criar um menu com  ListView, Ou seja, a pessoa clica em um botão, Ai aperasse um texto na  ListView  quando a pessoa clica no texto abre outro formulario, Como faço isso?